# Hide and show item when the user click on it using adapter

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, kotlin, adapter

My list is about questions and answer.

I've designed an item that has the question and answer and I'm planing to hide and show the answer, not the whole item (GONE/VISIBLE), when the user click on the question. So it will be more like expandable way.

Now this is my adapter:

```
class FaqExpandableAdapter internal constructor(private val context: Context, private var items: List<Faq>,private val callBack: AdapterCallBack?) : RecyclerView.Adapter<FaqExpandableAdapter.MyViewHolder>() {

    private val inflater: LayoutInflater = LayoutInflater.from(context)


    override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): MyViewHolder {
        val view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.item_question_faq, parent, false)
        return MyViewHolder(view)
    }


    override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: MyViewHolder, position: Int) {
        holder.txtQuestionFaq.text = items[position].question?.toString() ?: "-"
        holder.txtAnswerFaq.text = items[position].answer?.toString() ?: "-"
    }


    override fun getItemCount(): Int {
        return items.size
    }

    fun update(items: List<Faq>) {
        this.items = items
        notifyDataSetChanged()
    }

    inner class MyViewHolder(itemView: View) : RecyclerView.ViewHolder(itemView) {
        @BindView(R.id.txtQuestionFaq)
        lateinit var txtQuestionFaq: AppCompatTextView
        @BindView(R.id.txtAnswerFaq)
        lateinit var txtAnswerFaq: AppCompatTextView

        init {
            ButterKnife.bind(this, itemView)
        }


        @OnClick(R.id.relativeRowFaq)
        fun onItemClicked() {
            callBack?.onItemClicked(adapterPosition)
        }

    }


    interface AdapterCallBack {
        fun onItemClicked(position: Int)
    }

}
```

My last step is where to do the visibility action?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In `onBindViewHolder()` method, add below lines: (I use Java)

```
holder.txtQuestionFaq.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        holder.txtAnswerFaq.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    }
});
```

Answer (score 4):

Kotlin : Write onClick method on your onBindViewHolder function.

```
holder.txtQuestionFaq.setOnClickListener {
        holder.txtAnswerFaq.visibility = View.VISIBLE;
    }
```